# Function which create an object using a constructor and return completed object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating objects using my object constructor. I am nesting those objects like:

```
Object = {
    property: {
        property123: "test",
        property321: true,
    },
    property2: {
        name: "Mike",
        age: 20,
    }
};
```

and to give you more detail, you can check my code on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8v2b9x7p/3/

As you can see I have created few objects like "weaponMastery", "sword", "axe", "weaponSkillType".

What I want is a function which will return "weaponMastery" which has all those objects stored(nested) inside of it.

This way other objects won't be global since I don't use them. I am only using "weaponMastery".

Currently all objects are global, all I want is "weaponMastery" to be global, any other are not necessary. If there is a better way to create my object, then let me know.

I was looking into a way to delete them but I didn't find any good solution for that either. Any help is appreciated thanks :)

Comment: The way I read your question is you want to organize things more cleanly to avoid globals. In my opinion, what you seek is modular JavaScript. With CommonJS (or another approach to modular JS), you can avoid globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented as I think what you are really looking for is modules. But here is how you can accomplish what you ask: variables are scoped to the function in JavaScript. So wrap all of your variable declarations in a function and only expose `weaponMastery` as a global. You can use an anonymous function as a wrapper. It'll look like this:

```
(function() {
  ...
})();
```

Any variable declared inside with `var` will only be scoped within that function. If you want to expose a variable to the global scope, you can prefix it with `window.` so say `window.weaponMastery`.

Here is your code with that approach:

```
(function() {
    var weaponSkillType = function (level, experience, maxExperience, image, name) {
        this.level = level;
        this.experience = experience;
        this.maxExperience = maxExperience;
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
    };
    var sword = new weaponSkillType(0, 0, 10, "sword", "Sword");
    var axe = new weaponSkillType(0, 0, 10, "axe", "Axe");
    var mace = new weaponSkillType(0, 0, 10, "mace", "Mace");
    var staff = new weaponSkillType(0, 0, 10, "staff", "Staff");
    var ranged = new weaponSkillType(0, 0, 10, "ranged", "Ranged");
    var fist = new weaponSkillType(0, 0, 10, "fist", "Fist");

    sword.strength = function () {
        return this.level * 2;
    };
    sword.swordStrength = function () {
        return player.isSword ? this.strength() : 0;
    };
    sword.agility = function () {
        return this.level * 1.5;
    };
    sword.swordAgility = function () {
        return player.isSword ? this.agility() : 0
    };

    axe.strength = function () {
        return this.level * 2;
    };
    axe.axeStrength = function () {
        return player.isAxe ? this.strength() : 0;
    };
    axe.endurance = function () {
        return this.level * 1.5;
    };
    axe.axeEndurance = function () {
        return player.isAxe ? this.endurance() : 0;
    };

    mace.endurance = function () {
        return this.level * 2;
    };
    mace.maceEndurance = function () {
        return player.isMace ? this.endurance() : 0;
    };
    mace.wisdom = function () {
        return this.level * 1.5;
    };
    mace.maceWisdom = function () {
        return player.isMace ? this.wisdom() : 0;
    };

    staff.intelligence = function () {
        return this.level * 2;
    };
    staff.staffIntelligence = function () {
        return player.isStaff ? this.intelligence() : 0;
    };
    staff.wisdom = function () {
        return this.level * 1.5;
    };
    staff.staffWisdom = function () {
        return player.isStaff ? this.wisdom() : 0;
    };

    ranged.strength = function () {
        return this.level * 1.5;
    };
    ranged.rangedStrength = function () {
        return player.isRanged ? this.strength() : 0;
    };
    ranged.dexterity = function () {
        return this.level * 2;
    };
    ranged.rangedDexterity = function () {
        return player.isRanged ? this.dexterity() : 0;
    };

    fist.agility = function () {
        return this.level * 1.5;
    };
    fist.fistAgility = function () {
        return player.isFist ? this.agility() : 0;
    };
    fist.dexterity = function () {
        return this.level * 2;
    };
    fist.fistDexterity = function () {
        return player.isFist ? this.dexterity() : 0;
    };

    window.weaponMastery = new Object();
    weaponMastery.sword = sword;
    weaponMastery.axe = axe;
    weaponMastery.mace = mace;
    weaponMastery.staff = staff;
    weaponMastery.ranged = ranged;
    weaponMastery.fist = fist;
})();


function test() {
    var html = '';
    for (weapon in weaponMastery) {
        html += weapon + ', ';
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html;
};
test();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxtdhtts/

Comment: Also @vihan1086 pointed out it is dangerous to use `for ... in ...` and I agree with him -- that is a separate question/issue though but you should do a search here or on google on that topic.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and for additional info about "modular JavaScript" I will look into those topics too. Also I search about "for in" and I found that it is bad to use it on arrays, not object properties. If you could give me more info about this I would appreciate that a lot :) I will keep looking for that topic meanwhile.

Comment: @Mariusz I don't think it's a big deal it is just something to watch out for if you end up hitting some bugs. I prefer doing `Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) { ... });` but ES6 has some nicer ways to do it. No worries!

Comment: Hey, thanks again. I have no idea what ES6 is but I will read about it. I will also keep in mind your way of doing this for future reference. Thanks :)